# how to calculate average ages between two dates in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column of DNR dates (DATECOL) and a column of DNR ages (AGECOL), and I'd like to find the `AVERAGE` age within AGECOL between a specific date period

Cells B5 and C5 is my fixed date period that I'd like to search between.

I have tried using the below and tried `sumproduct`, but I'm not getting anywhere. The below doesn't get rejected, but it doesn't show the average age of the ages between the dates.

```
=COUNTIFS(DATECOL,">="&B5,DATECOL,"<="&C5,AGECOL,AVERAGE(AGECOL))
```

I can get the DATECOL to work on its own, and `AVERAGE(AGECOL)`, but I can join them to get the result I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AVERAGEIFS:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(AGECOL,DATECOL,">="&B5,DATECOL,"<="&C5)
```